# Effect of very high pressures on molar fractions of binary mixtures

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, physical-chemistry

I got the following Px curve of the binary mixture of ethane and octane at a constant temperature of 348.15 K from some literature data:
[image]

And I have checked similar data for other mixtures and with regards to changing pressure, the mole fraction of a compound rarely seems to intersect the pure component vertical line which would be at 1 in the horizontal axis (which is something you would see at constant pressure and changing temperature).

I assume that has to do with criticality of compounds at high pressures, and that perhaps it might be difficult to collect data at those conditions. But I'm not too sure whether that is correct, and I am even less sure on how to articulate that. Does anyone here know, what would be the challenges in collecting further data at higher pressures?

Thanks!

Comment: What is Px? And what is the meaning of the graph? Changing the pressure does not likely change the mole fraction of  a mixture (unless it triggers a chemical reaction).  Moreover: is the point at 0.5 MPa and 0.57 mole fraction correct? I am asking because it is a single point far from the others, but I cannot say if it is strange, since I do not understand what the graph is.

Comment: The vapor pressure of pure octane at this temperature is about 0.02 MPa.  Have you tried comparing your curve with what is predicted by Raolt's Law?

Answer (score 0):

When temperature is higher than the critical temperature of a component the $Pxy$ graph does not connect to the pure component axis. Remember that the axes represent the pure compounds and that the point where the bubble and dew lines meet is the saturation pressure of the compound. There is no saturation pressure above the critical temperature, which means that the $Pxy$ graph must detach from the axis.

[image: Pxy graph of CO2-C5]

This figure for the system CO$_2$-normal pentane shows how this detachment occurs when temperature is increased above the critical temperature of carbon dioxide (304.12 K). In this case the bubble and dew lines meet at the top with slope zero: this represents a critical point of the mixture.

If temperature is further increased above the critical temperature of pentane (469.7 K) the graph detaches from both axes and the $Pxy$ graph becomes a closed loop with two critical points, one at the top and one at the bottom of the loop.

The figure is from [this book](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265050437_Fundamentals_of_Chemical_Engineering_Thermodynamics) (p. 451).